# self.__dict__ return keyError

Tags: python

Hi everyone I'm new to python and I have the following class:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    #some definitions

  def executeAFunction(self, name)
    self.__dict__[name]
  
  def doSomething():
    #some code
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to use the function "doSomething" by calling executeAfunction('doSomething')

With the previous code I have a key error on self.**dict**[name] for the value 'doSomething'

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code which shows how you call the execute method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for something like this you'd be better off using `getattr`. It takes a string exactly as described.

You could rewrite `executeAFunction` as

```
def executeAFunction(self, name):
    return getattr(self, name)()
```

If you wanted to use `__dict__` you'd have to do something like

```
def executeAFunction(self, name):
    A.__dict__[name](self)
```

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` contains the instance attributes, but not the class attributes (they're on the `__dict__` of the class itself). If you want to perform lookup the way method calls work (so it'll pick up and bind methods), you shouldn't access `__dict__` directly, just use [the `getattr` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) which is designed for the precise purpose you're using it for (performing access with a string as if you're doing dotted attribute lookup):

```
def executeAFunction(self, name):
    getattr(self, name)  # This only looks it up, matching your code; call as getattr(self, name)()
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it works well by now !